# Is it possible to get a mount/speeder before lvl 25?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I am currently lvl 16 in my first play through of Star Wars the Old Republic. In visiting the trainer, I see that when I reach lvl 25, I can buy the speeder skill and then purchase a speeder. On the last few planets I have visited, however, I have seen multiple people in the lvl 10-20 range with speeders. How is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you finish the first chapter of your character, you  unlock [the Legacy System](http://www.swtor.com/info/legacy).

Upon reaching Legacy System level 2, you can train speeder ability at Character level 10.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had no idea what the legacy system was.